# BottomSheetBehavior half expanded height

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Is there way to set exact half expanded height(in px) instead of half expanded ratio (`setHalfExpandedRatio`)?
I need to control the expanded height of `BottomSheet`, however I cannot use `setPeekHeight()` because it should be expanded to full screen as well.

Comment: can you add design or any image , how it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of these options:

```
app:behavior_halfExpandedRatio="0.5"
```

The ratio to be used to set the height of half-expanded state in proportion to parent, when fitToContents is false. Defaults to true half, 0.5, if not explicitly set. Ratio must be a float value between 0 and 1 and produce a half-expanded state height larger than the peek height for the half-expanded state to be operational

```
app:behavior_expandedOffset="90dp"
```

The top offset of the BottomSheet in the expanded-state when fitsToContent is false. The default value is 0, which results in the sheet matching the parent's top.